# proto3 does not allow "optional" field in type declaration in C# Visual studio compilation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, protocol-buffers

I have proto3 syntax in my proto file. One type has "optional" field, so vs says that "proto3 does not allow "optional" field in type declaration". All nuget packages related to grpc are up to date.

Any suggestions for this? Project can't be compiled because of this error

Comment: `optional` in the context of proto3 was a late addition (which means "field presence" more than anything else); if it isn't compiling, then the `protoc` being used is old. The build tools package probably needs updating; what does your csproj look like re protobuf/grpc packages?

Comment: @MarcGravell
 <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.21.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="2.46.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.47.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.47.0">

Comment: @MarcGravell It is resharper problem, not vs.

Comment: Then talk to the resharper folks, I guess :)

Comment: Do you need to have the `optional` keyword? Every field is optional by default in proto3

Comment: @ClémentJean That's proto file give me the developer, It can't be modifyed actually. So I investigate that this issue is caused by Resharper. Can I disable proto check in resharper? I can't disable this extension

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense. Maybe you can check this: [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Ignore_Parts_of_Code.html#ignore-projects-with-frozen-or-third-party-code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Ignore_Parts_of_Code.html#ignore-projects-with-frozen-or-third-party-code). I'm not that familiar with Resharper so this might not be useful.

Comment: @ClémentJean already solved problem, in this section (same as you shown) , disable proto check